# FILEMAKER SQL - Fetch column2 from records with distinct column1

Tags: sql, filemaker

How do I find a distinct set of records based upon one field while returning a different field from those records?

```
ExecuteSQL ( "SELECT DISTINCT account FROM Albums2"; ""; "" )
```

How do I get another field returned in this type of query?

My goal is fetch 1 record from 1 instance of each account in the list. I am going to populate a global with the id's from the records so that the accounts show in a portal. Then I want to select an account so that all records from the account will show in another portal.

Dan's answer below works perfectly:

```
SELECT account, MAX(id) FROM Albums2 GROUP BY account
```

Comment: Do you mean like `SELECT DISTINCT account, Name FROM Albums2`

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT account gives me 70 records. From each of these records I would like to return the id. SELECT DISTINCT account, id gets all records in the table as every id is unique.

Comment: Ok let's suppose you have two records `{Account: abc, id:123}` and `{Account: abc, id:456}` which id would you want and how do you decide? Perhaps if you added sample data and expected output and any rules we'd have a shot at answering your question.

Comment: Records: {Account: abc, id:123}, {Account: abc, id:456}, {Account: xyz, id:987} and {Account: xyz, id:654} would return only 1 instance of each account from which I want the id. Result: {Account: abc, id:123}, {Account: xyz, id:987}

Comment: ok why? Because it's smaller? Do you want the fields for the smallest ID per account?

Comment: I just need one record from 1 instance of each account in a list. I am going to populate a global with a list of the accounts in a portal so I can click the account and all records from the account will show in another portal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologize for syntax error in my original answer. I no longer have Filemaker, but this code below will work with SQL. Does Filemaker 12 allow the SQL "GROUP BY" syntax? If so, it would solve the problem like this:

```
SELECT account, MAX(id) FROM Albums2 GROUP BY account
```

Explanation (assuming it works in Filemaker 12):
Rather than using DISTINCT to combine rows, you can use the GROUP BY syntax instead. To do that, you will also need to use an aggregate function like MAX() for the id column to indicate which of the non-duplicated id values to retain in the combined result.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In Filemaker 12 this expression gives an <?>: ExecuteSQL ( "SELECT DISTINCT account, MAX(id) FROM Albums2"; ""; "" ). Perhaps FM SQL needs different syntax?

Comment: My Filemaker is older, so I didn't get a chance to check it before I typed it in. Looks like my syntax has a grouping error. Testing another possibility now...

Comment: I updated my answer. I have confirmed that it works in another SQL compliant database. I don't have access to Filemaker at the moment, but in theory that should work if Filemaker allows GROUP BY.